# Is it possible to arrange items in pageview like listview with custom animation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

I am trying to achieve the following design. The first issue is when using pageview the current index item appears to be in the centre. I want a list like behaviour. But want to keep track of the current index and upcoming index so I could use an animated Container to make the animation.

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/2564256/screenshots/13623742/media/8614cdd2261a93cd65c949f1c68852f8.mp4

Comment: you can use normal `ScrollController` for getting the scrolling position

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I actually need the current index so I could Apply animation on the third Item when it comes to screen. Just like the reference.

Comment: do you have every item with the same width? if so, simply divide the scroll position by item width